# JSON Validator giving me error

Tags: json

I'm trying to parse deploy but I'm getting an error. The global.json is:

```
   {
    "applications": {
        ”MyApp”: {
            "applicationId": "7OI1Gk555Tr1CnrQ8bqplgImxMDJFTFfxaYUaPAZ",
            "masterKey": "Udzp2AaPb7WLg3aYtHqRyShliJU3nV98ak3P6IGi"
        },
        "_default": {
            "link": ”MyApp”
        }
    },
    "global": {
        "parseVersion": "1.3.1"
    }
   }
```

JSON Validator is giving me the error:

```
Parse error on line 2:

...cations": {        ”MyApp”: {
----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', '}'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of  `”MyApp”` use  `"MyApp"` it will work fine.the first one is not parse-able to json because it will not treat it as string as shown in your error stated.